# Dividing a set (C++)

Tags: c++, stl, set

I've got a `std::set<int>` which has `n` items in it. And I want to get rid of `n-k` bigger elements and keep the first (least) `k` elements. How should I do so? Is there a pre-defined function for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `std::set` is ordered.

```
std::set<int>::const_iterator i = myset.begin();
std::advance(i, k);
myset.erase(i, myset.end());
```

Comment: `std::advance(i, k);`, surely?

Comment: Shouldn't be `std::set<int>::iterator` instead of `std::set<int>::const_iterator`?

Comment: And in case it isn't obvious, `advance` doesn't bounds-check `k`, so make sure `k <= myset.size()`. Which is sort of implicit in the question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use the erase function :

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/erase/